# Ksoap2 - Android Build SOAP Request with Multiple Namespace definitions

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap, ksoap2

I am building SOAP Request Message using KSoap2-android version 3.3.0

My second namespace for Element 'n1' not added even though i added it with
SoapEnvelope.setMapping()

```
    <in1 xmlns:n1="http://event.api.company.com">      
  .....
```

**I am expecting the Request Message (CORRECT) in this Format:**

```
    <v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<v:Header/>
<v:Body>
    <updateStatus xmlns="http://service.api.company.com"
        id="o0" c:root="1">
        <in0>1604509</in0>
        <in1 xmlns:n1="http://event.api.company.com">
            <n1:actionDate>2014-09-02T05:18:20.156+0000</n1:actionDate>
            <n1:ActionTypeDTO>                    
                <n1:id>1</n1:id>
                <n1:name>Other</n1:name>
                <n1:description>Enter the description of the action taken.</n1:description>                    
            </n1:ActionTypeDTO>
            <n1:description>notes1</n1:description>
            <n1:name>system</n1:name>
        </in1>
        <in2>NEW</in2>
    </updateStatus>
</v:Body>
```

**But i am getting This (WRONG) after Ksoap build the Message:**

```
    <v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<v:Header/>
<v:Body>
    <updateStatus xmlns="http://service.api.company.com"
        id="o0" c:root="1">
        <in0>1604509</in0>
        <in1>
            <actionDate>2014-09-02T05:18:20.156+0000</actionDate>
            <ActionTypeDTO>                    
                <id>1</id>
                <name>Other</name>
                <description>Enter the description of the action taken.</description>                    
            </ActionTypeDTO>
            <description>notes1</description>
            <name>system</name>
        </in1>
        <in2>NEW</in2>
    </updateStatus>
</v:Body>
```

**This is my Function using KSOAP2-Android API:**

```
    public void updateStatus(long in0, ActionDTO in1){

    SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    soapEnvelope.implicitTypes = true;
    soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;

    SoapObject soapReq = new SoapObject("http://service.api.company.com","updateEventStatus");

    soapEnvelope.addMapping("http://event.api.company.com","in1",new ActionDTO().getClass());

    soapReq.addProperty("in0",in0);
    soapReq.addProperty("in1",in1);
    soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapReq);


    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url,timeOut);


    httpTransport.call("http://service.api.company.com/updateEventStatus", 
                       soapEnvelope);
    }
```

See following was not added in the Soap request:

```
    <in1 xmlns:n1="http://event.api.company.com">      
    <n1:actionDate>2014-09-02T05:18:20.156+0000</n1:actionDate>
  .....
  .......
  .....
```

Can Anybody help me what i am doing wrong... soapEnvelope.addMapping() function
seems not working correctly. OR am i missing something setting or flag to tell KSOAP??

I removed some code to make it clean to understand, sorry for that....
Thanks in advance for the Help ...

Comment: It would be easier if you show wsdl file. But you can try http://easywsdl.com generator. It supports many namespaces in soap requests/responses. Unfortunatelly it is not free.

Comment: Hi, thank you. i will try. But unfortunately i cannot post my wsdl file.

Answer (score 0):

some how figured out to solve the issue for now.

It might be Useful if somebody using 'Wsdl2Code' to generate Java Code as I am.

(WSDL2CODE.com engine will generate the classes and methods for connecting Soap Services From Android and iPhone!)

In the Wsdl2code generated DTO Classes change the following:

```
    public void getPropertyInfo(int index,
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo info) {

    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        **info.namespace = "http://event.api.company.com";**
        info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        info.name = "id";
        break;
    case 1:
        **info.namespace = "http://event.api.company.com";**
        info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        info.name = "name";
        break;      
    }
}
```

Then it will generate the SOAP Request as i mentioned in the Question (CORRECT).